# How to control line endings output by lua DOS<==>Unix

Tags: windows, unix, mercurial, eol

I am using luadoc and running it on Unix and windows, unfortunately the output is different on each system because of the DOS/Unix line endings, this really confuses my source control as it thinks every file has changed (mercurial). How can I make lua use one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about lua, but you might want to solve this at the SCM level, Mercurial has the [EolExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/EolExtension) for that.

That being said, you're probably missing some feature of luadoc.

Comment: @Sam Mackrill: yep, better let the SCM figure out what to do. After all, that's (part of) what they're supposed to help you with.

Answer (score 1):

[Mercurial FAQ 7.4](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/FAQ#FAQ.2BAC8-TechnicalDetails.What_about_Windows_line_endings_vs._Unix_line_endings.3F)